# Angular: How to defer return until after the $http request succeeds

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, http

In my main module I want to create a service that parses a json file and pushes the contents to an array, after I would like service to have the array be returned so it is easily accessible by any of the controllers.     The issue is the function is running before the $http request is complete so it always returns an empty array

```
dashModule.factory('dataFetch', function($http) {
    var emailArray = [];

    $http.get('../data/emails.json').success(function log(obj) {
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            emailArray[i] = obj[i];
        }
    });

    return {
        test: function() {
            return emailArray;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: You should try logging out the error using the .error(data, status, headers...). At first glance, this should work. So I think something is wrong with the way you are getting the json data, or the json data isn't available.

Comment: if I console.log(obj) in my for loop it displays the correct json data, console.log(emailArray) in the for loop the array displays as it should. Only when it comes to return it bypasses the $http request

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @AnfaA you should try putting the return statement inside the success() method.

Comment: @CourtneyNguyen you cant have a return within a method, the service fails when it doesn't return something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use promise, like:

```
dashModule.factory('dataFetchService', function($http) {
    var myReq = function() {
        return $http.get('../data/emails.json').then(function(response){
            return response.data;
        });
    };
    return { myReq: myReq };
});
```

and

```
function getMyReq($scope, dataFetchService) {
    var myReqPromise = dataFetchService. myReq();
    myReqPromise.then(function(result) {        
        console.log(result);
    });
}
```

Comment: do I put the getMyReq function in the controller?

Comment: @AnfaA yes that goes into controller